# How to set password in APIView - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to set password of user whose i am saving data. Comment line i was trying to set but it is not setting and error is comming `set_password is not defined`. How can i set a password whose instance i am saving in `APIView`.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
class EmployeeAddAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwrgs):

        serializer1 = EmployeeRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer2 = EmployeeProfileSerializer(data=request.data)

        user_role = ACLRoles.objects.get(id=4)

        if serializer1.is_valid():

            print(serializer1.validated_data['email'])
            # password = set_password(random_password)
            user = serializer1.save(
                username = serializer1.validated_data['email'],
                # password = password
            )

            if serializer2.is_valid():
                serializer2.save(
                    user_id = user.id,
                    user_company_id = self.request.auth.application.company.id,
                    user_role_id = user_role.id
                )

            print(serializer2.errors)

            return Response(serializer1.errors, serializer2.errors)

        return Response(serializer1.errors, serializer2.errors)
```

Previously in my app i was setting password some like this:

```
new_user = ur_form.save(commit=False)            
new_user.username = new_user.email
new_user.set_password(random_password)
new_user.save()
```

Comment: You need to use set_password() which is a method of the User class, so you either need a User class instance or an user object

Comment: how can i do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible way to call `make_password` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/auth/hashers/) from `django.contrib.auth.hashers` and assign your value there. This will be like following

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

def post(self, request, *args, **kwrgs):

        serializer1 = EmployeeRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer2 = EmployeeProfileSerializer(data=request.data)

        user_role = ACLRoles.objects.get(id=4)

        if serializer1.is_valid():

            print(serializer1.validated_data['email'])
            # password = set_password(random_password)
            user = serializer1.save(
                username = serializer1.validated_data['email'],
            )

            random_password = User.objects.make_random_password()
            obj = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user.id)
            obj.set_password(random_password)
            obj.save()

            if serializer2.is_valid():
                serializer2.save(
                    user_id = user.id,
                    user_company_id = self.request.auth.application.company.id,
                    user_role_id = user_role.id
                )

            print(serializer2.errors)

            return Response(serializer1.errors, serializer2.errors)

        return Response(serializer1.errors, serializer2.errors)
```

Comment: But i am not sending password it is randomly generated

Comment: @HuzaifSayyed you can pass your random generated password to serializer and make_password parameter and save from serializer. Also what you just edit both will work. Just one concern,  get a user instance is a DB-operation, if you have proper indexing that it should not take any time. Based on DB Index and your system user, we should always reduce unnecessary DB request.